# Macro that defines macro returning struct constant

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

I'm writing tokenizer.  I have `Token` struct:

```
defmodule Token do

  defstruct type: :text, str: ""

end
```

I want to define some common token constants (`Tokens.double_quote`) to use in function pattern matching:

```
defmodule Tokenizer do
  require Tokens

  #def tokenize(<<char>> <> buf, %Token{type: :double_quote, str: "\""} = current_token, acc) do
  def tokenize(<<char>> <> buf, Tokens.double_quote = current_token, acc) do
    # ...
  end

  def tokenize("\"" <> buf, current_token, acc) do
    # ...
  end

  def tokenize(<<char>> <> buf, current_token, acc) do
    # ...
  end

end
```

I decided to use macros, because I cannot use functions (not during match) or module attributes (not visible outside module).

Macro returning struct constant works:

```
defmodule Tokens do
  import TokenMacro

  # This works
  #defmacro double_quote, do: quote do: %Token{type: :double_quote, str: "\""}

  # This doesn't work
  token double_quote, :double_quote, "\""

end
```

Macro that defines macro returning struct constant doesnt't work:

```
defmodule TokenMacro do

  defmacro token(name, type, str) do
    quote do
      defmacro unquote(name), do: %Token{type: unquote(type), str: unquote(str)}
    end
  end

end
```

I get `CompileError`:

```
tokenizer.ex: invalid quoted expression: %Token{str: "\"", type: :double_quote}
expanding macro: Tokens.double_quote/0
```

What is wrong with token macro?

Is there simpler solution?

Comment: `defmacro unquote(name), do: Macro.escape(%Token{type: unquote(type), str: unquote(str)})` works. I _think_ this is because `defmacro` itself is a macro but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: @dogbert you should post that as an answer so others can find it too.

Comment: A map is not a valid quoted expression, hence why it has to be `Macro.escape`d.

Comment: @Dogbert Yeah, I second Onorio, you should, you saved my afternoon